# 'Unknown layer: Functional' when I load a model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, kaggle, resnet

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape = (150, 150, 3), pooling = 'max')
final_output = Dense(264, activation = 'softmax')(model.output)
model = Model(inputs = model.input, outputs = final_output)
```

This is the model I trained in colab. I tried to load this in Kaggle error is shown : 'Unknown layer: Functional'

complete traceback:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 model = tk.models.load_model('../input/cornell-submission-model/resnet50_3.h5')
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py
> in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
> 182     if (h5py is not None and (
> 183         isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
> --> 184       return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
> 185
> 186     if sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(filepath, pathlib.Path):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
> 176     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
> 177     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
> --> 178                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)
> 179
> 180     # set weights
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/model_config.py
> in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
> 53                     '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
> 54   from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import deserialize  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
> ---> 55   return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
> 56
> 57
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py
> in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
> 107       module_objects=globs,
> 108       custom_objects=custom_objects,
> --> 109       printable_module_name='layer')
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py
> in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects,
> custom_objects, printable_module_name)
> 360     config = identifier
> 361     (cls, cls_config) = class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(
> --> 362         config, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
> 363
> 364     if hasattr(cls, 'from_config'):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py
> in class_and_config_for_serialized_keras_object(config,
> module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
> 319   cls = get_registered_object(class_name, custom_objects, module_objects)
> 320   if cls is None:
> --> 321     raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ': ' + class_name)
> 322
> 323   cls_config = config['config']
>
> ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional

Please help me with this

Comment: Hi...Have you find the resolution for this?

Comment: @KunalP    here is the model I was talking about kaggle.com/timothyalexjohn/moa-imbalanced-multi-label please download the model and try loading the model to tf.keras you will also get an error... Please help me understand the error and rectify it...Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The ResNet50 model contains a number of repeating blocks. I am not familiar with Colab, but based on the error you received, my guess is that the block of layers is implemented as **custom** layer and you should have its implementation defined and declared in custom_objects dictionary

Comment: here is the model I was talking about kaggle.com/timothyalexjohn/moa-imbalanced-multi-label please download the model and try loading the model to tf.keras you will also get an error... Please help me understand the error and rectify it...Thank You