# How to load old Keras model in Tensorflow 2.0 with custom lambda layers?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load [this](https://github.com/daniegr/EfficientPose/blob/master/models/keras/EfficientPoseI.h5) model which contains custom functions and lambda layers, using the following code:

```
def load_efficient_pose_model():
    custom_objects = {'BilinearWeights': keras_BilinearWeights, 'Swish': Swish(eswish), 'eswish': eswish, 'swish1': swish1}
    model = keras.models.load_model('my_location/EfficientPoseII.h5',custom_objects=custom_objects)
```

When using Tensorflow 1.13.1 and Keras, everything works correctly.
However, when I am using Tensorflow 2.7 (with built-in Keras), the following mistake happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ....
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2_runtime/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/daniegr/Programming/EfficientPose/utils/units.py", line 90, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'K' is not defined
```

I've also tried loading the model in Tensorflow 1.13.1 and saving model and weights separetly, but the problem remains.

When serializing the model to JSON, I am getting these interesting lines:

> ```
>         {
>             "name": "lambda_1_res1",
>             "class_name": "Lambda",
>             "config": {
>                 "name": "lambda_1_res1",
>                 "trainable": false,
>                 "function": [
>                     "4wEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAABTAAAAcwQAAAB8AFMAKQFOqQApAdoBeHIBAAAAcgEAAAB6Ri9Vc2Vy\ncy9kYW5pZWdyL1Byb2dyYW1taW5nL0VmZmljaWVudFBvc2UvbW9kZWxzL2VmZmljaWVudG5ldHMv\nbW9kZWwucHnaCDxsYW1iZGE+HQEAAPMAAAAA\n",
>                     null,
>                     null
>                 ],
>                 "function_type": "lambda",
>                 "output_shape": null,
>                 "output_shape_type": "raw",
>                 "arguments": {}
>             },
> ```

My guess is that somehow the old model saves parts of code which access `K` as backend, which is not available in Tensorflow 2.

I went through these related questions [so1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339426/unknown-layer-functional-when-i-load-a-model) and [so2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192435/tensorflow-model-with-keras-and-tensorflow-addons-layer-is-not-getting-loaded), but could not find an answer.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the author of [efficient-pose](https://github.com/daniegr/EfficientPose) library, the problem was that Tensorflow2.7 is currently unsupported. With Tensorflow 2.5 it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with not being able to access the internal variables in your saved model, you could use the lower-level API [`tf.saved_model.load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load) to load your model. This only loads the graph and weights so you can still run the model code, but it won't be as convenient to use.

Comment: I've tried that and it did not solve my problem, but thanks for trying to help me.